# Core Data relationships not mapped with RESTkit

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I am struggling to get a proper mapping of Core Data relationships using RESTkit 0.20.0-pre6.

I want to map this JSON:

```
{ "items" : [ {"id" : 2001, "itemAttr1" : "..."}, ...<more items>... ],
  "rooms":  [ {"id" : 3001, "items": [2001, ...<more item id's>...] }
```

to a corresponding Core Data model:

```
Entity ItemMO (Attributes "id", "itemAttr1", Relationship "room" to RoomMO)
Entity RoomMO (Attributes "id", Relationship "items" to ItemMO)
```

The attributes are mapped fine, but the relationships are empty.

I have tried using `RKConnectionDescription` as described [here](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKConnectionDescription.html), using this code:

```
NSEntityDescription *roomEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RoomMO" inManagedObjectContext:self.context];
NSRelationshipDescription *itemsInRoom = [roomEntity relationshipsByName][@"items"];
RKConnectionDescription *connection = [[RKConnectionDescription alloc] initWithRelationship:devicesInRoom keyPath:@"devices"];
[roomMapping addConnection:connection];
```

I have also tried using a simple `RKRelationshipMapping` to no avail:

```
[itemMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"room" withMapping:roomMapping]];
```

I must be missing something simple as this should not be an exotic case for RESTkit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I got it working.
The trick was to add an extra attribute 'roomId' on ItemMO for the foreign key.

```
Entity ItemMO (Attributes "id", "roomId", "itemAttr1", Relationship "room" to RoomMO)
```

Then tell RESTkit about the relation:

```
[itemMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"room" connectedBy:@{@"roomId" : @"id"}];
```

It seems as if RESTkit cannot establish the relation without the extra foreign key attribute.

Comment: +1 for explicitly ruling out the capacity for RESTKit to do this mapping without the extra foreign key attribute.