# RestKit: Mapping of primitive relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, mapping, restkit

Hope the title describes it right.

I got the following JSON:
`{"regions":[{"name":"Region 1", "zipcodes":["80432", "80433"]}, ...]}`

And I have two entities `Region` and `ZipCode`:

```
@interface Region : NSManagedObject
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *zipCodes;
@end

@interface ZipCode : NSManagedObject
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * zipCode;
  @property (nonatomic, retain) Region *region;
@end
```

I try to fill both using the following code:

```
RKEntityMapping *regionMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Region" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];

//[regionMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"zipCodes" connectedBy:@{@"zipCode" : @"zipcodes"}];

[regionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name":@"name"}];

RKResponseDescriptor *regionDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:regionMapping pathPattern:@"/regions" keyPath:@"regions" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:regionDescriptor];
```

As you can see, I also tried to use `addConnectionForRelationship: connectedBy:` which I saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398309/core-data-relationships-not-mapped-with-restkit), but with no success. I guess I have to create a separate `RKEntityMapping` for `ZipCode` but I have no idea on how to glue that together with my existing code, without overloading the `RKResponseDescriptor`.

Does anyone of you have dealt with a similar situation? How did you solve it? The example from the link above is pretty similar, but unfortunately the solution posted is very incomplete.

Note 1: Existing code writes `name` into my database, but doesn't create any relationship with `ZipCode` nor does it write any zip code into my database

Note 2: I am using the latest RestKit Version (0.20pre)

Note 3: You could save my life here ;)

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your mapping for an entity called `DeliveryRegion` instead of `Region`?

Comment: Thanks for the hint - just updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar and found that `addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:mapping:` worked best. From my understanding, use relationship mappings for nested relationships (same request) and connections for creating relationships across multiple requests.

To do this you might want to reformat your JSON like so:

```
{"regions":[
    {"name":"Region 1", "zipcodes":[
        {"zipcode": "80432"},
        {"zipcode": "80433"}]},
    ...]}
```

...and change your mappings to the following:

```
RKEntityMapping *regionMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Region" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[regionMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"name"]];

RKEntityMapping *zipCodeMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"ZipCode" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[zipCodeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"name"]];

[regionMapping addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"zipcodes" mapping:zipCodeMapping];

RKResponseDescriptor *regionDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:regionMapping pathPattern:@"/regions" keyPath:@"regions" statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:regionDescriptor];
```

I haven't tried mapping a relationship with the JSON format you are using (array of strings rather than an array of dictionary elements) but you might be able to do it by playing around with the zipCode attribute mapping.